# NLTK Named Entity recognition for a column in a dataset

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

Thanks to "alvas" code from here , [Named Entity Recognition with Regular Expression: NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398536/named-entity-recognition-with-regular-expression-nltk) and as an example:

```
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree

def get_continuous_chunks(text):
    chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    prev = None
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for i in chunked:
        if type(i) == Tree:
            current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in i.leaves()]))
        elif current_chunk:
            named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
            if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
                continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
                current_chunk = []
        else:
            continue

    return continuous_chunk

txt = 'The new GOP era in Washington got off to a messy start Tuesday as House Republicans,under pressure from President-elect Donald Trump.'
print (get_continuous_chunks(txt))
```

the output is :

> ['GOP', 'Washington', 'House Republicans', 'Donald Trump']

I replaced this text with this : `txt = df['content'][38]` from my dataset and I get this result :

> ['Ina', 'Tori K.', 'Martin Cuilla', 'Phillip K', 'John J Lavorato']

This dataset has many rows and one column named 'content'.My question is how can I use this code to extract names from this column for each row and store that names in another column and corresponding rows?

```
import os
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')
text = df['content']
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
print (classified_text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `apply`:

```
df['ne'] = df['content'].apply(get_continuous_chunks)
```

For the code in your second example, create a function and apply it the same way:

```
def my_st(text):
    tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
    return st.tag(tokenized_text)

df['st'] = df['content'].apply(my_st)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if I want to do the same with this code what can I do ?

Comment: I added it to my question.Thank you

Comment: Added an example to the answer.