# Nltk Tokenizing and add Bigrams by keeping the sentence

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I am working on my bachelorthesis and have to prepare a corpus to train word embeddings.
What I'm thinking about is if it is possible to check a tokenized sentence or text for ngrams and then exchange these single tokens with the ngram.

To make it a bit clearer what i mean:

**Input**

var = ['Hello', 'Sherlock', 'Holmes', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Mr', '.', 'Watson','.']

**Desired Output**

```
var = ['Hello', 'Sherlock_Holmes', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Mr_Watson','.']
```

I know Mr. Watson is not the perfect example right now. But I am thinking about if this is possible.

Because training my word2vec algorithm without looking for ngrams does not do the job well enough.

```
class MySentence():
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname
        print('Hello init')
 
    def __iter__(self):
        
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            txt = []
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                txt = nltk.regexp_tokenize(line, pattern='\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')
                tokens = [token for token in tokens if len(token) > 1] #same as unigrams
                bi_tokens = bigrams(tokens)
                
                yield tri_tokens = trigrams(tokens)
     
sentences = MySentence(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

N-grams are just sequences of adjacent words but they don't have to make sense language-wise. For example, "Hello Sherlock" and "Holmes my" could be 2-grams. Rather, it sounds like you are looking a more sophisticated tokenization with language-specific context, or entity recognition ("Sherlock Holmes"), which itself requires a trained model. Check out NLTK's [documentation](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) regarding [`nltk.ne_chunk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836058/nltk-named-entity-recognition-to-a-python-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)or [rule-based chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398536/named-entity-recognition-with-regular-expression-nltk?noredirect=1&lq=1). Or for out-of-the-box solutions, [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities)'s named entity recognition and tokenization capabilities, to get started.