# Why I am not getting 'PERSON' nad 'GPE' as label after chunking using `nltk.ne_chunk`?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tagging, chunking

I am using `nltk.ne_chunk()` like this:

```
sent="Azhar is asking what is weather in Chicago today? "
chunks = nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent)), binary=True)
print(list(chunks))
```

And getting oitput like this:

```
[Tree('NE', [('Azhar', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('asking', 'VBG'), ('what', 'WP'), ('is', 
'VBZ'), ('weather', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), Tree('NE', [('Chicago', 'NNP')]), ('today', 'NN'), 
('?', '.')]
```

But I am expecting an output like this:

```
[Tree('PERSON', [('Azhar', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('asking', 'VBG'), ('what', 'WP'), ('is', 
'VBZ'), ('weather', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('Chicago', 'NNP')]), ('today', 'NN'), 
('?', '.')]
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [NERs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition), am I right?

Comment: Yes I am looking for named entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the Spacy library and download the relevant model (`en_core_web_sm`) which is explained [here](https://spacy.io/usage), you can simply extract Named-Entities!

```
import spacy
NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
sent="Azhar is asking what is weather in Chicago today? "
text1= NER(sent)
for word in text1.ents:
    print(word.text,word.label_)
```

output:

```
Azhar PERSON
Chicago GPE
today DATE
```

**UPDATE**

`nltk.ne_chunk` returns a nested `nltk.tree.Tree` object so you would have to traverse the Tree object to get to the NEs. `tree2conlltags` from `nltk.chunk` would do something like that!

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags

sentence = "Azhar is asking what is weather in Chicago today?"
print(tree2conlltags(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))))
```

output in IOB format:

```
[('Azhar', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('asking', 'VBG', 'O'), ('what', 'WP', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('weather', 'NN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('Chicago', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('today', 'NN', 'O'), ('?', '.', 'O')]
```

more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398536/named-entity-recognition-with-regular-expression-nltk)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will use spacy for my task. Could you also clarify me why nltk is not returning these labels, I think it should as I have seen articles and questions in stack overflow where it is retuning these tags

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is very helpful and I find that spacy is doing better job in labelling the tokens